# Is it Possible that APK file created by PhoneGap Platfrom ,run in ios?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am working in cross-platform like Phone-Gap

```
 public class MainActivity extends DroidGap  {
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index2.html");
}
```

Above is simple Hello-World program,  by

```
 cordova-2.7.0.js
```

Now my APK ( for android ) is ready. I want to know that is there any way to install this APK in ios. Even i know that Apple mobile support .ipa extension. But here i am using PHONEGAP ,this is cross-platform .Above code is not for Native Application

```
index2.html
```

is just a simple html file.
My another Question is that - PhoneGap Support .xhtml file ? , actually i want to use PrimeFace UI in our Mobile application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know that is there any way to install this APK in ios

That is not possible, sorry. You are welcome to use the same PhoneGap sources to create an iOS application, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare.Thanks for your response..So mean to say i can use my HTML file as it is , and i have to change necessary code in Objective C to call all these HTML file then finally i will get .ipa file.

Comment: @BlueGreen: You may not have to have to change any native code. You will have to go through a PhoneGap build process to get an iOS app. Whether you use PhoneGap's tools in conjunction with XCode, or use the hosted PhoneGap Build service, is up to you.

Comment: Thanks again.One thing i want to say you are really a help man.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. Is is possible to use .xhtml file in Android or how can i use Prime face feature in our Android App.?

Comment: @BlueGreen: I do not know what "Prime face feature" is and so I cannot comment upon it. I would assume that XHTML files work, though it may be that you will need the `.html` file extension. I rarely see XHTML files with `.xhtml` extensions, as the file's XHTML-ness is handled through the `DOCTYPE` and such.